# "Он был весь исполнен ритуала"?

Tags: выбор-слов

Можно ли, среди прочих характеристик, упомянуть такую:

> Он был весь исполнен ритуала.

(О "правильном" поведении/разговоре в общественном месте - музее: светском, доброжелательном, компетентном, дотошном.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть, так:

***Он был весь исполнен условностями  ритуала (ритуальными условностями).***

Имеется в виду условный порядок поведения, разговора.

**РИТУАЛ**, 2. Выработанный обычаем или установленный **порядок** совершения чего-л.;

**УСЛОВНОСТЬ** 2. Общепринятая норма поведения, не имеющая обычно какого-л. смысла, но соблюдаемая в силу **традиционности**, консервативности общества или какого-л. круга людей.

**Условности этикета. Светские условности**. Познать условности общения. Отказаться от условностей. Вести разговор мешали условности. Соблюдать **условности дипломатических приёмов**.

Answer (score 1):

[**исполнить**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?all=x&word=%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C), -ню, -нишь; исполненный; -нен, -а, -о; ***св.*** кого чем или чего. Книжн.
Наполнить каким-либо чувством. *Исполненный отваги.*

*Старец был **исполнен любви** к человеку, к твари...

**Светом и радостью исполнено** это видение...*

***Исполнен печали,***
Хотел бы я сделаться птицей
И, вымеряв дали,
В родную Литву возвратиться...
А. Якштас

Думаю, что говорить "исполнен ритуала" неверно (ритуал — это не чувство).

Мне кажется, можно написать так:
**Он был весь исполнен ответственности за соблюдение ритуала.**

Answer (score 1):

Он был весь образцом светских манер.

Он был весь эталоном пристойности.

Он был весь погружённым в ритуал.

Он был весь погружён в условности ритуала.

Answer (score 1):

Не будет ли чуть лучше так:

**Он был весь преисполнен ритуалом.**

Подобное сочетание не так режет слух и даже находится в гугло-книгах:

> Мир, который возникает в спектакле, — это мир, преисполненный формой,
>   каноном, ритуалом.

Comment: Гриззлик, почти. Автор выбрал "преисполнен ритуала". *Некто спросил: «В глубокой древности были преисполнены добродетели, но не были преисполнены ритуала. Дети бегали [за матерями], жеребята и телята ходили [за лошадьми и корова­ми] . К чему еще ритуал?» Отвечаю: «О дети, о телята! То, чем они преисполнены по отношению к матери, – это не то же са­мое, чем они преисполнены по отношению к отцу. По отношению к матери они преисполнены любви, по отношению к отцу преис­полнены благоговения...».* http://religa.narod.ru/han/han199220.htm